# Nice way to declare enums in C++ without bloating the namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, standards

I noticed that if I do something like this in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013:

```
namespace LogLevelEnum {
enum Type {
    ALL,
    FINEST,
    FINE,
    INFO,
    WARNING,
    SEVERE,
    OFF
};
}
typedef LogLevelEnum::Type LogLevel;
```

I can access the **enum** items using things like `LogLevel::INFO` and `LogLevel::WARNING`, but not by simply doing `INFO` or `WARNING`. I like it that way because it doesn't put as many symbols into the encompassing namespace.

However, I was wondering whether or not this is standard behaviour. I know classes and namespaces can be indexed using the `::` operator, but it makes a bit less sense for that to also work on enums, considering they simply dump everything in the namespace it's in.

Comment: Just use a [scoped enum](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: C++11 enum classes ?

Comment: @chris: Ah, I didn't know about these. I guess I'll use these. I still wonder how exactly the behaviour of what I was using is defined, though.

Comment: Wait a second, what did you achieve with the `LogLevel` typedef? Without it, you'd have to write `LogLevelEnum::INFO` just the same, just `INFO` wouldn't work because it's in a namespace. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"However, I was wondering whether or not this is standard behaviour."* It originally was a VC++ extension but got legalized in C++11, alongside scoped enums.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: With the typedef, you can do `void SetLevel(LogLevel level);` instead of `void SetLevel(LogLevelEnum::Type level);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I was wondering whether or not this is standard behaviour.

Yes provided you are using a C++11 compliant compiler and by standard you are referring to the C++11 standard.

> but not by simply doing INFO or WARNING.

This is because the enum is within the namespace scope. Have you tried `LogLevelEnum ::INFO` or `LogLevelEnum ::WARNING`?

> Nice way to declare enums in C++ without bloating the namespace

Use [Scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) i.e. `enum struct | class` instead of `enum` while defining the enum.

Comment: Regarding *"This is because the enum is within the namespace scope. Have you tried LogLevelEnum ::INFO or LogLevelEnum ::WARNING?"*, that was my intent. Note how I said *"I like it that way because it doesn't put as many symbols into the encompassing namespace."* Since your answer is essentially a summary of the comments and the comments answered my question, I'll accept it.